# Problems with SQLAlchemy and VirtualEnv

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, virtualenv

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy under a virtualenv on OS X 10.5, but cannot seem to get it to load whatsoever.

Here's what I've done

```
mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages test
easy_install sqlalchemy
```

I try to import sqlalchemy from the interpreter and everything works fine, but if i try to import sqlalchemy from a python script, I get the following error:

Here's the tutorial script from [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-sqlalchemy/)

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey

Base = declarative_base()
class Filesystem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'filesystem'

    path = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, path,name):
        self.path = path
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Metadata('%s','%s')>" % (self.path,self.name)
```

I try running 'python test.py' and this is the result:

```
$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey
  File "/Users/grant/Development/Aircraft/sqlalchemy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
ImportError: No module named ext.declarative
```

Here's what's in my sys.path

```
>>> import sys
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/Users/grant/Development/Python/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg
/Users/grant/Development/Python/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.4p2-py2.6.egg
/Users/grant/Development/Python/test/lib/python26.zip
/Users/grant/Development/Python/test/lib/python2.6
/Users/grant/Development/Python/test/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin
/Users/grant/Development/Python/test/lib/python2.6/plat-mac
/Users/grant/Development/Python/test/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/grant/Development/Python/test/lib/python2.6/lib-tk
/Users/grant/Development/Python/test/lib/python2.6/lib-old
/Users/grant/Development/Python/test/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/grant/Development/Python/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

Any ideas on what's going on??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed my own problem... I had another script named sqlalchemy.py in the same folder i was working in that was mucking everything up.

Comment: LOL, I had the same kind of problem with a different library.